# Refresh all does refresh the connections but doesn't refresh the tables

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection, excel-tables

I have three tables which pull data from SQL database.

When I click refresh all from the data menu, the connections refresh but only sum of the tables are refreshed.

When I right-click>refresh the tables themselves, they reflect the correct information (telling me that the connection was refreshed indeed).

I tried `ActiveBook.RefreshAll` and the following code too:

```vb
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable

For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next qt

Next wks

Set qt = Nothing
```

How can I refresh the table using VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

You should access the connections through Workbook. Example,

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim con As WorkbookConnection
  
    For Each con In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    ' Your Conditions, for example, check connection name etc. 
    ' If con.Name = "MyConnection" Then
        con.Refresh
    ' Else 
    ' Do your thing
    ' End if
    Next
End Sub
```